# Capture the Auto Suggest Pop Up message Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, popup, gmail

i am trying to capture a pop up message which is appearing when we put the cursor in "Choose Your Username" text box of gmail create account page. The pop up with message "You can use letters, numbers, and periods." should be captured in a variable and then it needs to be printed on console. But i am unable to find the element either by id or xpath.

Here is the code which i wrote:

```
package Default;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HandlingAjaxAutoSuggests {

WebDriver oBrowser;

@Test
public void AjaxAutoSuggests()
 {
    oBrowser = new FirefoxDriver();

    oBrowser.get("https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html");

     oBrowser.findElement(By.id("gmail-create-account")).click();

    oBrowser.findElement(By.id("GmailAddress")).click();

    String sText = oBrowser.findElement(By.id("gmail-address-infomessage")).getText();
    System.out.println(sText);      

  }

}
```

This code is not capturing the pop up message.

Can anyone of you please look into this code and provide me ideas to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you getting the id=gmail-address-infomessage?

Comment: If you go to source code by right rlcik - view source code then you will see                spellcheck="false">
  <span class="atgmail">@gmail.com</span>
  </label>
  <div class="infomsg" id="gmail-address-infomessage">
  You can use letters, numbers, and periods.
  </div>

Comment: Oh I know how to use the dev-tools. It's just that element does not show for me. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

this:

String sText = oBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.jfk-bubble")).getText();

works for me